# Getting Cinnamon back after copying over old configuration files?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ubuntu-12.04, cinnamon

I recently got a new computer and installed Mint Cinnamon.  I then copied over the contents of my home directory from my previous computer, which was using Ubuntu 12.04.  Upon rebooting, the Cinnamon desktop was replaced with what looks like a standard GNOME 3 desktop (applications/places bar up top, windows bar down at the bottom).

I actually like Cinnamon and want to restore my desktop back to using it.  Is there a simple way that I can do this?  Or did I break everything when copying over the home directory and its configuration files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably lost your Cinnamon settings but apart from that you should be OK. Just reinstall Cinnamon:

```
sudo apt-get remove cinnamon
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

I am not at my computer at the moment so I can't check the package name, it might be mint-cinnamon or something, just make sure you use the correct one.

Comment: Just tried this (including restarting) and it doesn't look like this did anything.  Sorry about that!

Comment: @templatetypedef, are you sure you are selecting a Cinnamon session at the GDM login screen? Otherwise, you will run your last session, gnome in your case.

Comment: @terdon- Just figured that out a second ago, and now it works. :-)  Thanks!